# Do paint fumes affect electronics?

Tags: painting, paint, safety

I'm planning on painting a home office but I don't want to have to move all my equipment out of the room. If I keep my equipment inside and move it all to the center of the room will the fumes affect my electronics?

Comment: Fumes, no; aerosolized paint, yes. If you are spray painting (and not rolling/brushing), move the equipment.

Comment: Some electronics have allergies... the only way to know is to have them tested.

Answer (score 2):

Seems very unlikely. Consider that lots of harmful industrial chemicals are used in the production of electronics to begin with.

Usually most people's concerns with VOC's associated with painting have to do with human health, especially the young and old. It's generally best to minimize any contact with these by ensuring lots of ventation and if possible, using a low VOC product. Latex based paints are preferable to oil based paints in this regard.

Comment: Benjamin moore paint is latex, correct?

Comment: They sell both types of paints, among other water/oil-based products. Read the labels to confirm.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Since most electronic circuit boards contain some form f switching or mechanical electrical adjustment, the fumes from paint can cause faulty connection between contact elements. If heat from the electronics is high enough, the heat can cause the chemicals in the air , to be drawn directly to components. I have found this to be a problem for selector type push buttons. You can tell this when you first push on the button if you have to some what break it free.(as if it was stuck in whatever the normal position is)

This can happen from closed but used paint cans from the paint that has been wiped off of the brisk and wet on the side of the cans when stored in areas of electrical operation. This is always been an issue with paint cans being stored in mechanical rooms of commercial blogs..

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it, instead of posting a separate answer. Thanks!